# Semantic UI multiple select dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, meteor, semantic-ui

Semantic UI generates a dropdown but not with the multiple selection possibility as I want. When I try the same code in a JSFiddle it works so it has to do with my project.

I use Meteor + Semantic UI + jQuery 1.11.4

```
Template.permissions.rendered = function () {
    $(".ui.fluid.dropdown").dropdown();
};
```

This initialising my dropdown but just making it possible to select one single option. (So it at least seams to run, same happens if I initialise directly in Chromes console)

```
<div class="twelve wide field">
    <label style="width: 250px">Add roles to user</label>
    <select name="skills" multiple="" class="ui fluid dropdown">
        <option value="">Roles</option>
        <option value="Role1">Role 1</option>
        <option value="Role2">Role 2</option>
        <option value="Role3">Role 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My understanding is that `multiple=""` should make it a multiple select?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67sq63rt/1/) where same code works. Have no clue why it is not working in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the Semantic UI dropdown was already added to my project but it seams like it was not. Running:

```
meteor add semantic:ui-dropdown
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: I dont know meteor. I used NPM to install smantic. Do I need to install ui-dropdown separately? Do I need to reference it somewhere? I am bit confused because dont know how meteor works.